# Directive inside another directive

Tags: angularjs

I've `ParentDirective` inside it I've `ChildDirective`, I defined array in the scope of the `ParentDirective`, and it's bound the view of the `ChildDirective`, but I notice that when I debugged the code, that the debugger reached to the `link` of the `ChildDirective` before the `link` of the `ParentDirective`, and it cause that it don't display anything in the view.

How can I fixed it?

Comment: Please post some code as well, preferably a runnable example like a Fiddle or Plunkr.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal order of execution and you cannot change this. This means you should coordinate the building of the view in the parent link function.